# Flutter cloud_firestore Filter.or using DocumentReference throws Invalid argument error

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We're using the `cloud_firestore` Flutter package (just upgraded to 4.9.3) and we're getting an error when using Filter.or with arrayContains: documentReference. The specific error message is `Invalid argument: Instance of '_JsonDocumentReference'`

Here's the query:

```
.where(
  Filter.and(
    Filter(PostKeys.type, whereIn: [PostType.creation.name, PostType.combination.name]),
    Filter(PostKeys.visibility, isEqualTo: ContentVisibility.public.name),
    Filter.or(
      Filter(PostKeys.ingredients, arrayContains: itemReference),
      Filter(PostKeys.tags, arrayContains: itemReference)
    )
  )
)
.orderBy(PostKeys.created, descending: true)
.limit(queryLimit);
```

**RESULT**: `Invalid argument: Instance of '_JsonDocumentReference'`

Even if we remove the Filter.or and instead just include one of the statements in the Filter.and, we get the same error:

```
.where(
  Filter.and(
    Filter(PostKeys.type, whereIn: [PostType.creation.name, PostType.combination.name]),
    Filter(PostKeys.visibility, isEqualTo: ContentVisibility.public.name),
    Filter(PostKeys.ingredients, arrayContains: itemReference),
  )
)
.orderBy(PostKeys.created, descending: true)
.limit(queryLimit);
```

**RESULT**: `Invalid argument: Instance of '_JsonDocumentReference'`

The changelog for `cloud_firestore` version `4.9.2` state "FIX(firestore): allow DocumentReference to be used to in Filter queries", but it doesn't appear to be working and we're not sure why.

As a reference, we're running the same query in our Prototype environment using Javascript and it works fine:

```
pq = query(collection(db, "posts"), 
  and(
    where('type', "in", ['creation','combination']),
    where("visibility", "==", CONSTANTS.visibility.public), 
    or(
      where('ingredients', "array-contains", itemRef), 
      where('tags', "array-contains", itemRef)
    ) 
  ), 
  orderBy("created","desc"), 
  limit(queryLimit)
);
```

**RESULT**: Works fine in Javascript (WebV9)

Comment: If you think this is a bug in the Flutter SDK for Firestore, it may be easier to get attention for that by filing an issue in the FlutterFire repo: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks, I'll do that.  I thought maybe posting here first would be quicker in case I was making an obvious mistake.

Comment: For that it'd help if we could see how `itemRef` and `itemReference` are initialized.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added that info and more into the bug report:  https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11682

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen you're a wizard.  I was able to get the query to work.  Based on your comment, I checked the initialization of the DocumentReference and it was `final itemReference = _itemsCollection.doc(item.reference.id);`. Instead of that, I just passed the existing `item.reference` into the query and it worked.  Not sure why that made a difference, but it did.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working Byron. Not sure what `_itemsCollection` is in that last comment, but if it works I guess it's not a bug after all. 